# How do I deploy my custom trained tensorflow 2.0 model into my react.js webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have converted my tensorflow model into a .tflite file, not sure if it is the correct format, but I tried uploading it onto firebase but it was not compatible with reactjs as it only gives the code snippets in Kotlin, Java and swift, whereas reactjs does not use any of the 3 as it is a Javascript library. I followed this tutorial where I used a cocoSsd model from tensorflow to detect my images, I am writing this to ask, what am I supposed to do in order for this reactjs app to use my custom trained model instead of the model provided by tensorflow, cocoSsd. 
I assume I have to host my model on a public web server and import it as an API?
Would appreciate if someone educate me on this, first time implementing a custom model onto a webapp, hence I am quite lost, thank you! 
My code snippet is below

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu";
//import "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl";
import * as cocoSsd from "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd";

const ObjectDetectorContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const DetectorContainer = styled.div`
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
`;

const TargetImg = styled.img`
  height: 100%;
`;

const HiddenFileInput = styled.input`
  display: none;
`;

const SelectButton = styled.button`
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0a0f22;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 260ms ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

const TargetBox = styled.div`
  position: absolute;

  left: ${({ x }) => x + "px"};
  top: ${({ y }) => y + "px"};
  width: ${({ width }) => width + "px"};
  height: ${({ height }) => height + "px"};

  border: 4px solid #1ac71a;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 20;

  &::before {
    content: "${({ classType, score }) => `${classType} ${score.toFixed(1)}%`}";
    color: #1ac71a;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.5em;
    left: -5px;
  }
`;

export function ObjectDetector(props) {
  const fileInputRef = useRef();
  const imageRef = useRef();
  const [imgData, setImgData] = useState(null);
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const isEmptyPredictions = !predictions || predictions.length === 0;

  const openFilePicker = () => {
    if (fileInputRef.current) fileInputRef.current.click();
  };

  const normalizePredictions = (predictions, imgSize) => {
    if (!predictions || !imgSize || !imageRef) return predictions || [];
    return predictions.map((prediction) => {
      const { bbox } = prediction;
      const oldX = bbox[0];
      const oldY = bbox[1];
      const oldWidth = bbox[2];
      const oldHeight = bbox[3];

      const imgWidth = imageRef.current.width;
      const imgHeight = imageRef.current.height;

      const x = (oldX * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
      const y = (oldY * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;
      const width = (oldWidth * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
      const height = (oldHeight * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;

      return { ...prediction, bbox: [x, y, width, height] };
    });
  };

  const detectObjectsOnImage = async (imageElement, imgSize) => {
    const model = await cocoSsd.load({});
    const predictions = await model.detect(imageElement, 6);
    const normalizedPredictions = normalizePredictions(predictions, imgSize);
    setPredictions(normalizedPredictions);
    console.log("Predictions: ", predictions);
  };

  const readImage = (file) => {
    return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => rs(fileReader.result);
      fileReader.onerror = () => rj(fileReader.error);
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  const onSelectImage = async (e) => {
    setPredictions([]);
    setLoading(true);

    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const imgData = await readImage(file);
    setImgData(imgData);

    const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
    imageElement.src = imgData;

    imageElement.onload = async () => {
      const imgSize = {
        width: imageElement.width,
        height: imageElement.height,
      };
      await detectObjectsOnImage(imageElement, imgSize);
      setLoading(false);
    };
  };

  return (
    <ObjectDetectorContainer>
      <DetectorContainer>
        {imgData && <TargetImg src={imgData} ref={imageRef} />}
        {!isEmptyPredictions &&
          predictions.map((prediction, idx) => (
            <TargetBox
              key={idx}
              x={prediction.bbox[0]}
              y={prediction.bbox[1]}
              width={prediction.bbox[2]}
              height={prediction.bbox[3]}
              classType={prediction.class}
              score={prediction.score * 100}
            />
          ))}
      </DetectorContainer>
      <HiddenFileInput
        type="file"
        ref={fileInputRef}
        onChange={onSelectImage}
      />
      <SelectButton onClick={openFilePicker}>
        {isLoading ? "Recognizing..." : "Select Image"}
      </SelectButton>
    </ObjectDetectorContainer>
  );
}
```

This webapp is basically asking for an image input, taking the image and throwing it to the model and displaying what the model detected.
Let me know if I'm too vague or if anything else is needed, thank you!

Comment: Remove all the styling that is unnecesary. With so much extra stuff you make debugging a nightmare for yourself...

Comment: All details needed are here https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd